# Dom Marker of Here Maps does not display the content which rendered by react

Tags: reactjs, here-api

This code works fine:

```
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = 'abc';
this.marker = new H.map.DomMarker(PositionToLatLng(position), {
  icon: new H.map.DomIcon(div),
});
```

While this code displays nothing:

```
const div = document.createElement('div');
ReactDOM.render('abc', div);
this.marker = new H.map.DomMarker(PositionToLatLng(position), {
  icon: new H.map.DomIcon(div),
});
```

DomMarker(DomIcon) should display any HTMLElement no matter it is created by DOM api or rendered by react.

Comment: How are you instantiating the Here map object in React since you need to add the marker to a map? Please add more code (to the point where you are adding the marker to the map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using `renderToStaticMarkup` and nesting the child component within.

```
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from 'react-dom/server';

// lifecycle method
const html = renderToStaticMarkup(children);
const icon = new window.H.map.DomIcon(html);
this.marker = new window.H.map.DomMarker({ lat, lng }, { icon });
```

Note: This is Server-side rendered.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring

If you're curious about DomIcon, in particular, their docs had a pretty good code sample:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-domicon.html

Comment: Not sure I totally understand what you're asking. Like how to make a dom element spin? https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-quick-introduction-to-css-animations-a1655375ec90/

Comment: Yes, but not exactly. We need set both anchor and rotation, which means, the center of the DOM corresponds to the interesting position after spinning. Since the default anchor is left-bottom of the DOM and the rotation point is the center of the DOM, it will leave the original position after spinning.

Comment: Huh interesting. I'd probably start with adding an event listener. Then look into an event like spin or rotate. Not sure about attaching to different positions inside the dom object. Might be able to use refs there https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-icon.html#h-map-icon__addeventlistener https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Hi Jack, I'll start a new topic.

Comment: Hi Jack, see "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58786541/anchor-and-rotation-for-dom-marker".