# Anchor and rotation for DOM marker

Tags: here-api

I can set the rotation to the css of the DOM marker in here map api. However, I can't set the anchor. That would lead to the origin of the spin deviate from the coordination of the marker. See the picture below:

[image]

How to resolve it?

The relevant code is like the following:

```js
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from 'react-dom/server';
import { PositionToLatLng } from './utils';

export class DomMarker {
  constructor(map, options) {
    const { position, children, angle, ...others } = options;
    this.marker = new H.map.DomMarker(PositionToLatLng(position), {
      icon: new H.map.DomIcon(renderToStaticMarkup(
        <div>
          <div
            style={{
              transform: `rotate(${angle}deg)`,
              cursor: 'pointer'
            }}
          >
            {children}
          </div>
        </div>
      )),
    });
    this.map = map;
    this.map.addObject(this.marker);
  }

  remove() {
    this.map.removeObject(this.marker);
  }
}
```

It works with "renderToStaticMarkup". But it renders nothing if I use "renderToDiv".

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export function renderToDiv(element) {
  const content = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(element, content);
  return content;
}
```

I print the return value of "renderToDiv", it looks like the following:

[image]

Comment: Yes, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The anchor parameters only works for `H.map.Icon`. Use CSS styles to center an `H.map.DomIcon`.

Assuming your icon is 24px width and height:

```
<div style="left: -12px; top: -12px;">
   // icon content
</div>
```

Comment: H.map.DomIcon() can only take string as parameter. I pass a domElement and it renders nothing. So, how can I get iconWidth by the HTML string? If it took domElement, I could use domElement.offsetWidth.

Comment: H.map.DomIcon _can_ take a domElement: https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics_api/h-map-domicon.html
You should add your code related to the icon creation.

Comment: ```const marker = new H.map.DomMarker(pos, { icon: new H.map.DomIcon(dom) });``` This code renders nothing. It works if I change "dom" to "string".

Comment: The real code is posted in my question. Please see it above.

Comment: Your `renderToDiv` function returns a domElement with an empty div, since the reference returned by `ReactDOM.render` is not returned, and assuming the element you're using is not stateless, in which case `ReactDOM.render` returns null. However that is beyond the scope of setting an anchor to `H.map.DomIcon`, so I recommend you to open a question under the react tag, and mark this one as answered if that's the case.

Comment: I print the return value of "renderToDiv", it is valid (see above). The same "renderToDiv" function works in other maps, such as bing map and google map.